# How can I parse a longer JSON file than a NSString?

Tags: iphone, json, nsstring, nsarray

I'm a bit stuck in a project.
I was writing some code to get a JSON file and store it in an NSString before parsing it into a NSArray.

But I get an error:

> 2010-10-27 20:59:44.813 GeraldKervyn[21752:207] -JSONValue failed. Error trace is: (
>       "Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=3 \"Unrecognised leading character\" UserInfo=0x7637890 {NSLocalizedDescription=Unrecognised leading character}"

I think the problem is related to the limited value that an NSString can take.

BTW this is the feed I'm using : http://www.geraldkervyn.com/api/get_recent_posts/

What would be the most convenient way to parse this into an NSArray ?

Thanks !

Comment: I get this when calling that Url: `ERROR: json is not a valid feed template.` And that is not valid Json, do you get something else?

Comment: I would trust the error to mean that you've encountered an invalid or unescaped character.  I've used `SBJSON` on even larger JSON strings in the past.

Comment: But http://www.jsonlint.com/ Has validated the JSON !

Comment: Could it be a charset problem, I see many \u2013 like chars. Maybe one of them is the culprit.

Comment: Might be. But I can't get it fixed. I'm also using SBJSON and have no clue what's going on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, Add the SBJson code to your project, courtesy of Stig Brautaset. Then do this...

```
 NSString *subject = @"http://www.geraldkervyn.com/api/get_recent_posts/";
 NSString *encodedSubject = 
    [subject stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

 NSString *test = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:encodedSubject]];
 SBJsonParser *parser = [[SBJsonParser new] autorelease];
 NSDictionary *json = [parser objectWithString:test];
 NSArray *values = [json objectForKey:@"posts"];
```